# SharePoint Search Issue

Tags: search

When I try to use the search button I get the following error "the search request was unable to connect to the Search Service"

Can someone tell me how to connect to the Search Service or whatever I'm able to do so I can do searches?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about SharePoint Online, it is currently in a degraded state.

> Current Status: Engineers have identified an issue with the Search
>   feature within the SharePoint Online service. Efforts are underway to
>   determine the root cause and to remediate impact.
>
> User Experience: Affected users are unable to perform searches,
>   including People Search and Content Based Search. Delve, Video
>   Portals, and custom solutions built on Office Graph are also impacted.

I am experiencing the same issue in my tenant.

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same issue in my tenant. Thankyou for the Info :-)

Comment: D you have info about; when it is going to be resolved?

Comment: no, Next Update by: Thursday, September 10, 2015, at 8:00 PM UTC

Comment: One last question, Where can I get the updates?

Comment: https://portal.office.com/admin/default.aspx or there are smart phone apps for Office 365 Administration, it requires global administration privs tho.

Answer (score 0):

Is it this? [The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2888383)